# What software and hardware are essential for developing for iPod? On a PC?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

I have an idea for a simple application to run on an iPod. I'm an experienced programmer but have no experience on iPod or any Mac or Apple operating system. What are the bare essentials in terms of hardware and software to begin developing using a PC as the development platform? Does the PC need to be running Linux?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414636/iphone-development-environment-from-scratch

Comment: “Does the PC need to be running Linux?” I'm not sure why you would think that, considering Macs don't run Linux either.

Answer (score 7):

You can't run applications on an iPod, unless it is an iPhone or iPod Touch.  For that platform, you need a Mac running Leopard, Xcode (free), and the SDK (free).

Comment: You can, if that application is a game.  :)  I have an IPod video, and there are tons of games for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the term [Hackintosh](http://lifehacker.com/348653/install-os-x-on-your-hackintosh-pc-no-hacking-required) - then you could run Xcode. Not done it myself, and you might need to buy some specific hardware :)

You might find this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources) useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Macintosh and Xcode to develop software for the iPhone/iPod touch.

There is some new software that was announced this week called ModelBaker that allows you to create Ajax iPhone apps, but it only runs on a Macintosh as well.