# Development environment for Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, ios4

Dear all.
Today, I start to learn iOS. I don't know what tool I need to install to develop IPhone applications.
At this time, I have a HP laptop which is running with Windows 7.

If you know about this, please tell me.

Thanks all.

Binh Nguyen

Comment: I've got bad news. You need a mac and xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Development Environment (from scratch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414636/iphone-development-environment-from-scratch)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nguyen, If you want to use your HP laptop for developing for iPhone then its possible. I have seen people do it. But it will back fire at you and cost you more, coz macs GUI is very heavy for non mac devices and it causes them to crash all the time. My friend installed mac on VM ware and it caused him around 159$ to repair his pc (he was working on final cut pro). so if you want to just learn the objective c language then its ok, but it wont be good for actual software development and deployment. And plus `Xcode is very heavy software (3GB approx), its the worlds best editor` but you will face a lot of problems if you dont use mac and probably wont want to work on it again. So take my advice if you just want to learn objective c, you can probably do that by using some unix compiler too for compiling the code and s.

Hope this might help you decide. Bye

Edit: here is some of the links that will get you started with objective c and `objective c on windows`

http://www.ehow.com/how_5148893_start-learning-objectivec-windows.html

http://www.roseindia.net/iphone/objectivec/objective-c-windows.shtml

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535198/best-way-to-learn-objective-c

http://techgossipz.blogspot.com/2011/01/learn-objective-c-on-windows.html

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Ronbin. At this time, I just want to learn iOS and XCode only. That is the reason why I dont want to by a physical Macintosh now (Maybe I will never develop actual software).

Answer (score 2):

You will need an Macintosh computer in order to develop native iPhone applications. You will need to download XCode which will include everything you need. If you want to actually run the applications on a physical device you will need to register with Apple as a developer.

Comment: I will not buy an physical Macintosh. I think that I can install an virtual Macintosh, right?

Comment: I don't think so. Not officially anyways.

Comment: It is definitely possible to run OS X inside a virtual machine on a PC.

Answer (score 2):

These people are WRONG. You don't need a mac to develop iphone apps. There are many options for Iphone Development on PC.

[Airplay SDK](http://www.airplaysdk.com/) is a great FREE tool for developing fast, high quality, portable code. It deploys to PC, mac, iphone, droid, and many others.

[DragonFire SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/) costs money, and I would not use it before Airplay, but go ahead and check it out if you want.

There are others I'm forgetting but you can do a quick search on google or stackoverflow for them.

Comment: Thanks cable279. This's so great! But I just want to use the SDK provide by Apple. Maybe the SDKs suggested by you will not be stable.

Comment: Airplay seems very stable to me, check out their website, they even go so far as to say you can test on pc and deploy to iphone knowing there will be no differences. And they keep fairly up-to-date with new iOS features. But if you want to do GUI apps then the regular Apple SDK is the way to go, you just need a mac for it :P

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to test your software so that it actually works you need to run it on a physical device: an iPhone/iPad/iPod. In order to download to a physical device you need to have the $99 software license from Apple. If you don't have that you can also not sell your software in the app store. So the path of least resistance is to get a cheap mac book/mac mini and an iPod -- as a bare minimum, all other roads are full of pitfalls.